# Removing style css from inside div tags

Tags: html, css

Instead of hard coding widths into a div tag with the style tag parameter how could I alter the following so that I can instead use a css file to alter the widths. I cant try it as I am on my cell in the middle of practically nowhere but would the following I have provided work and if not could somebody advise on the corrections!

Currently:

```
<div class="test_ml" style="width:936px"></div>
<div class="test_mr" style="width:912px"></div>
<div class="test_mm" style="width:912px"></div>
```

Will The following work?

CSS File:

```
div.test_ml { width:936;}
div.test_mr { width:912;}
div.test_mm { width:912;}
```

HTML File:

```
<div class="test_ml"></div>
<div class="test_mr"></div>
<div class="test_mm"></div>
```

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/ to lazy to make a answer

Comment: Your `width`s require units (whether pixels (`px`), `em`, points (`pt`) or any other).

Comment: If only there was a simple way to try this out...some program that would allow one to, say, browse stylized web pages...

Comment: @JackManey i was about to answer you before seeing 7894 reputations for you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yess it will

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfBg3/1/)

```
<div style="width:936px;border:1px solid red">a</div>
```

is the same has

```
<div class="test_mlx">a</div>
div.test_ml {
    width:936px;border:1px solid red
}
```

Warning, user DavidTomas made a point :

> Your widths require units (whether pixels (px), em, points (pt) or any
>   other). – David Thomas

Answer (score -1):

As @David Thomas saied before, you should add the unit type right after the quantity.

for example:

```
div.test_ml { width:936px;}
```

By the way, I recommend that you will use softwere that will autocorrect you and autofill your code, and will make your life much easier & shorter.